# Some feature of the equation

Tags: functions

I have the equation for $x$:
$$f(a, b, x) = 
 8(b^2 + a^2x^4/16)^{3/2} - ab^2(16b^2 + 3a^2x^4)=0,$$
where $a$, $b$ are parameters, and I have the function:
$$y(a,b,x(a,b)) = 
 1 - \frac{2 + a^2x^2(a,b) - 4a\sqrt{b^2 + a^2x^4(a,b)/16}}{4 - 
     8ab^2{(b^2 + a^2x^4(a,b)/16})^{-1/2}},$$
then I plot two graphs:
$$y(a_0,b,x(a_0,b)),$$
$$y(a,b_0,x(a,b_0)),$$
and they look the same. It seems to be due to the first equation for $x$, but I'm not sure, and I don't know how to prove this feature analytically. I discovered this on the graph using the next code in Wolfram Mathematica:

```
f[a_, b_, x_] = 8*(b^2 + a^2*x^4/16)^(3/2) - a*b^2*(16*b^2 + 3*a^2*x^4);
v[a_, b_] = x /. FindRoot[f[a, b, x], {x, 40}];
y[a_, b_] = 1 - (2 + a^2*v[a, b]^2 - 4*a*Sqrt[b^2 + a^2*v[a, b]^4/16])/(4 - 8*a*b^2/Sqrt[b^2 + a^2*v[a, b]^4/16]);
Plot[{y[1, x], y[x, 1]}, {x, 1, 8}, PlotRange -> {0.372, 0.375},AxesOrigin ->{0,0.372}, PlotStyle -> {{Thickness[0.02], Blue}, {Thickness[0.006], White}}]
```

[image]

Comment: To make things easier on yourself, substitute $b = \beta/4$ and $x = \sqrt{\zeta}$, then multiply through by 16 to get $2(\beta^2+a^2\zeta^2)^{3/2}-a \beta^2(\beta^2+3a^2\zeta) = 0$

Comment: Your two graphs are defined by values $a_0, b$ and $a, b_0$, but you have not described anywhere what $a_0, b_0$ are and how they relate to $a, b$.

Comment: After examing your code, it appears that your description of $a, b$ as "parameters" is incorrect. You are treating $a_0, b_0$ as parameters, but $a, b$ are free variables, and your plots are of $y$ against $b$ with $a_0$, and $y$ against $a$ with $b_0$. $x$ is only an intermediary dependent variable. Such a confused descriptiion makes it much harder for others to figure out what you mean, and thus less likely to be able to offer help.

Comment: Also, are you finding the graphs to be the same for arbitrary values of $a_0, b_0$, or only when $a_0 = b_0$, or even just when $a_0 = 1, b_0 = 1$ as in your graph? Or is it that for any $a_0$, you are finding there is a $b_0$ that makes the graphs the same?

Comment: @eyeballfrog, thanks, I've done this. Also there should be $3a^2\zeta^2$ at the end.

Comment: @PaulSinclair, thanks. $a$ and $b$ are parameters, $a_0$ and $b_0$ are their partial values. The observed feature is that the graphs of functions $y(a_0,b,x(a_0,b))$ and $y(a,b_0,x(a,b_0))$ look the same. I checked this feature for some values of $a_0$, $b_0$. It means, that parameters $a$ and $b$ are interchangeable. So, let's plot the graph for $y(b)=y(a_0,b,x(a_0,b))$, then replace $a_0\to b_0=a_0$, $b\to a$ and plot the graph for $y(a)$. We obtain the previous graph. I'd like to understand this feature of interchangeable of parameters $a$, $b$ analytically, if it's so.

Comment: When you have several variables, and describe some of them as "parameters", but not others, what this usually means is that the function is actually a family of functions of the *other* variables (the "free" or "independent" variables). The "parameters" are considered fixed values that determine which function in the family is being used. This is the picture you created, reinforced by the third variable being $x$, by far the most commonly used free variable, particularly when graphing with $y$ being the dependent variable. And what does "partial value" even mean?

Comment: @PaulSinclair, a "partial value" of parameter $a$ means a fixed value $a_0$ of parameter $a$. I assumed that "parameter" can be a variable. I'll explain my question differently. Let's we express $x$ from it's equation $f(a,b,x)=0$ and obtain the function $x(a,b)$ of two variables. Then we substitute $x(a,b)$ into function $y(a,b,x(a,b))$ and obtain function $y_1(a,b)$. Let's consider function $y_2(\alpha,\beta)=y_1(b,a)$. The graphs for $y_1(c,b)$ and $y_2(c,\beta)$ are the same, where $c$ is a constant. It means, that $y_1(a,b)=y_1(b,a)$. I'm trying to prove or disprove this analytically.

Comment: In 40 years of advanced mathematics, I have heard these referred to as "initial values", "particular values", or "fixed values", but never "partial" values, which to me suggests an entirely different relationship to the variable. I would express your question something like "Define the function $v(a,b)$ implicitly by $f(a,b,v) = 0$. Fixing a value $c$, I have found by graphing that the functions $x \mapsto y(c,x,v(c,x))$ and $x \mapsto y(x,c,v(x,c))$ appear to be the same. For example, when $c = 1$ ..."

Comment: @PaulSinclair, concerning "partial value" it's just "lost in translation", since English isn't my native language. Yes, your formulation is correct. But my question seems to be easier, since I don't need to define function $x(a,b)$, because I know its implicit equation $f(a,b,x)=0$. I just try to prove that $a$ and $b$ are interchangeable variables in function $y(a,b,x(a,b))$, that is they enter the function $y$ symmetrically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get rid of the constants inside the radicals by making the substitution $x = 2\sqrt{\zeta b / a}$. After dividing the $x$ equation through by $8b^3$ and simplifying the expressions, the equations now take the form
$$
(1 +\zeta^2)^{3/2} - 2ab(1 + 3 \zeta^2) = 0
$$
$$
y(a,b,\zeta) = 1 - \frac{1+2ab \zeta -2 ab\sqrt{1+ \zeta^2}}{2-4ab/\sqrt{1+x^2}}.
$$
What we see here is that $a$ and $b$ only show up as the product $ab$. This means if you swap the values of $a$ and $b$, you get the same value of $y$, explaining the feature you found.

Comment: Thanks, that's that I needed. I just tried to prove that variables $a$, $b$ enter into my equation and function as a product $ab$.